# android how to handle thread with animation

Tags: android, multithreading, animation

How can i `throw any object(Stone)` `continuously` to a `moving Horizontally object`?
I have used a thread which can throw stone using translate animation continuously but the memory usage is very much and my device get slows down after 3-4 min.How to resolve dis problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you would be best of implementing your own [`SurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html). In it, you can draw animated objects (using a dedicated thread) much more feely than using view-animations. (You will of course have to rewrite parts of your code for this, but it might be for the best in the long run).
If you feel you want to try the `SurfaceView`, I recommend looking through the [Lunar Lander](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html) example from android.

Example:

```
public class ThrowView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnGestureListener{
    //The OnGestureListener can detect a fling motion.
    private class DrawingThread extends Thread{
        private final float timefactor = 0.0001f; //This is used to make the animation a bit slower. Play with this value if the animation seems too be to slow or too fast.
        private final float damp = 0.9; //This is used to slow down the object. If it stops too fast or slow, this is the value to change.
        private float stoneX = 0; //The x-coordinate of our stone object. Use this when drawing.
        private float stoneY = 0; //The y-coordinate of our stone object. Use this when drawing.
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(running){
            Canvas c = null;
            try{
                c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) { 
                    updatePhysics();
                    doDraw(c); //doDraw is not in this example, but it should essentially just draw our object at stoneX, stoneY.
                }
            }finally{
                if(c!=null) surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c); 
            }
            SystemClock.sleep(40);
        }
        private void updatePhysics(long time){
            //Calculate how much time has passed since last step:
            time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            dT = (time1 - time2)*timefactor;
            time2 = time1;

            //Move the stone in x depending on the time and velocity:
            stoneX += vX*dT;
            //Decrease the velocity:
            vX -= dT*damp:
        }
    }
    protected volatile float vX = 0; //This is the x-speed. To be able to throw in y too, just make another variable for that.
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        //This is our onFling, here we take the velocity of the users fling and set our variable to that.
        //Note that this value is based on pixels.
        vX = velocityX;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        //The onDown should return true so onFling can be activated:
        return true;
    }
}
```

*This example is made according to the Lunar Lander sample for ease of use. Many methods (that were not necessary for this example) are omitted here, but can be implemented according to Lunar Lander.*

Comment: I have used Surface view bu nw how can I throw that object using gestures onFling().Would u plz provide me some example....

Comment: I added an example of the methods to use for the throwing. The missing parts you can see how to make in lunar lander, but with slight adaptation of course. :)

Comment: can we do that "I want to throw the objects onFling() by gesture listener on the target that is continuously moving" so can we do both in a single Surface View......How can we do that?????

Comment: I have used your approach n I m able to throw the object but simulataneously cannt handle both....ie throw object and move target at same time.....Any approach to do dat????

Comment: Add some variables for the target, and update those in the updatePhysics() method in a suitable way. (maybe something like targetY = 200*Math.sin(time1);) Then you can also draw the target in doDraw().

Comment: hello Jave,i m able to handle two canvas in a surface view but how can i throw multiple objects....I really dont have any idea to do in canvas?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have been without a network for the last days.  
If you want multiple objects, you can create a stone-class, with the necessary variables, and a list or array of stone objects. Then you update each object in your updatePhysics method :)